# How to set a "net user" output equal to a variable

Tags: batch-file

I have a net user output that tells me if a user with a certain username has an active account or not. The command is as follows (followed by the command line output below):

```
net user "username" /domain | find /I "Account active"
Account active               Yes
```

how do I set a variable equal to that output? I write the following code in a batch file and it doesn't seem to be working:

```
set x=net user "username" /Domain | find /I "Account Active"
echo %x%
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect a portion of a command's output to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377443/how-do-i-redirect-a-portion-of-a-commands-output-to-a-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more straightforward method would be to just pipe into another `Find` command.

```bat
Set "IsActive=No"
Net User "UserName" /Domain 2>Nul | Find /I "Account active" | Find /I "Yes" >Nul && Set "IsActive=Yes"
```

You may also prefer `FindStr` to deal with both at once by using a wildcard match, perhaps something as simple as `active.*yes`.

Comment: How might I do this for a more complicated field like Full name? Is that possible? Thanks for your help on the original question!

Comment: @NicolasKlebusits, you'd need to provide more information, _preferably now as a new question_!